# Behaviour of a own haskell function: does sometimes stop to produce (easy to produce) results

Tags: performance, haskell, space

I wrote a haskell function to produce prime factorizations for numbers until a certain threshould – made of some prime factors. A minimal working code can be found here:
http://lpaste.net/117263

The problem: It works very good for "threshould <= 10^9" on my computer. But beginning with "threshould = 10^10" the method don't produce any results on my computer – I never see (even not) the first list element on my screen. The name of the critical function is "exponentSets". For every prime in the list 'factors', it computes the possible exponents (with respect to already chosen exponents for other primes). Further commends are in the code. If 10^10 works good on your machine, try it with an higher exponent (10^11 ...).

My question: what is responsible for that? How can I improve the quality of the function "exponentSets"? (I'm still not very experienced in Haskell so someone more experienced might have an Idea)

Comment: `10^10` overflows a 32 bit integer. Check that this is not the issue by adding `print threshould` in your main and confirming you are using 64 bits integers.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Yes I checked it and it uses 64-bit ints.

Comment: Well the exact value on which this occurs is ``2 ^ 32 + 1`` on my machine. Is this true for yours too? **NOTE:** Yes I checked, I am using 64-bit integers.

Comment: For me it's also 2^32 + 1

+RTS -K1G -kc64K doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though you are using 64-bit integers, you still do not have enough capacity to store a temporary integer which is created in `intLog`:

```
intLog base num =
    let searchExtend lower@(e, n) =
        let upper@(e', n') = (2 * e, n^2) -- this line is what causes the problems
    -- some code
    in (some if) searchExtend (1, base)
```

`rawLists` is defined like this:

```
rawLists = recCall 1 threshould
```

Which in turn sets `remaining_threshould` in `recCall` to

```
threshould `quot` 1 -- same as threshould
```

Now `intLog` gets called by `recCall` like this:

```
intLog p remaining_threshould
```

which is the same as

```
intLog p threshould
```

Now comes the interesing part: Since num `p` is smaller than your base `threshold`, you call `searchExtend (1, base)`, which then in turn does this:

```
searchExtend (e, n) = 
      let (e', n') = (2 * e, n ^ 2)
```

Since `n` is `remaining_threshould`, which is the same as `threshould`, you essentially square `2^32 + 1` and store this in an `Int`, which overflows and causes `rawLists` to give bogus results.

```
(2 ^ 32 + 1) ^ 2 :: Int is 8589934593
(2 ^ 32 + 1) ^ 2 :: Integer is 18446744082299486209
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that answer! Well done! Changing the type to Integers does the job.